# Why do I need braces at the end of an array declaration in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I have been googling for a while and every tutorial taught me that to create an array, you just do the following:

```
var persons = [String]
```

But I am moving from swift code to iOS development learning material and everywhere it is now

```
var persons = [String]()
```

Why do we need those braces at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you're mixing up 2 concepts: variable declaration, and variable assignment.

To *declare* an empty Array in Swift, you have to explicitly state what Types the array can hold. You do this either with the long-hand definition:

```
var persons: Array<String>
```

Or the shorthand syntax (preferred):

```
var persons: [String]
```

Note the use of a colon ":" instead of equals "=".

Both of these are saying "I'm declaring the existence of a variable (not constant)  called 'persons' which will be a mutable Array full of Strings. Right now it's undefined though."

In Obj-C, you can put any kind of Object into an NSArray, which means you can't really be sure what you'll get out of one. Declaring the Array contents in this way is one of Swift's Type safety features. You can be confident that `persons` will only ever contain `String` instances.

To *assign* a value to your variable, meaning that it doesn't just have a definition but also has a valid object assigned to it in memory, you have to actually initialize the Array:

```
var persons = [String]()
```

This is essentially a shorthand way to initialize an empty Array that will hold a certain Type, without passing any parameters to the init: method. After this, `persons` actually has a value, which is a completely empty Array that is only allowed to contain Strings.

Alternatively, Swift's Array Type has a 2nd initializer that lets you pass parameters:

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)
```

You could use this to create an Array w/a set length and initial values:

```
let immutableBobsArray = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: "Bob")

println(\(immutableBobsArray))  \\ ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob"]
```

See ["Collection Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) in the Apple's Swift Programming Guide, and also [the Array entry in the Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW1)

Comment: I thought      var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]      was enough to initialize it in swift. But like apple guide puts it: You can create an empty array of a certain type (without setting any initial values) using initializer syntax:

var someInts = [Int]()                                            So am I right in thinking that you only require those braces when initializing an empty array and not one where you are populating the array during the declaration/initiation like in var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]

Comment: Correct - the "declaration" is `var name: [TypeInTheArray]`. It only uses a colon ":". The assignment operator "=" actually sets the variable on the left side to the expression on the right side. In your example, you can even leave off the `: [String]` part because Swift can use Type inference to figure out what type the array contains. It's obvious that "Eggs" is a String, so you can just say `var shoppingList = ["Eggs", "Milk"].` You're setting it equal to a populated Array w/literal syntax that lets you skip initializing an empty array with `[String]()` & then filling it.

Comment: yeah i knew about type inference but the parenthesis confused me as I was unfamiliar with the syntax. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

`[String]` is the name of a type in Swift. Specifically, it is the type `Array<String>`, which is a parameterized version of the generic `Array<T>` type. Just like the statement `var number = Int` doesn't make any sense unless you explicitly tell the compiler that you are constructing an instance of a specific type.

What you want is either `var persons = [String]()`, or, if you want to specify the initial value of your variable with an array literal, you can do `var persons: [String] = []`. Note that in the second option we are forced to specify the type of our variable since Swift's type inference cannot figure out the type of an empty array (what values does `[]` hold?).